# issues with mysql server timezone and jdbc connection

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat7

I am getting this error when connecting to my database.

> com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed
>   database URL, failed to parse the connection string near
>   '=Australia/Sydney;useSSL=false;'.

this is my connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false;serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney;useSSL=false;
```

My environment:

- java 8
- mysql-connector-java:6.0.6
- Mysql server community:5.7.18

Any idea what is wrong?

thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `;`, try: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=Australia/Sydney&useSSL=false`

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/6.0/en/connector-j-reference-jdbc-url-format.html